# How can I pass integer into string for sql query

Tags: java, sql

I have written a program that extracts data from an SQL table:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/petcare";
        String password = "ParkSideRoad161997";
        String username = "root";
        // Step 2: Making connection using
        // Connection type and inbuilt function on
//        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement p = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
 
        // Try block to catch exception/s
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            // SQL command data stored in String datatype
            String sql = "select * from inbox";
            p = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = p.executeQuery();
 
            // Printing ID, name, email of customers
            // of the SQL command above
            System.out.println("inboxId");
            int inboxId;
 
            // Condition check
            while (rs.next()) {
 
                  inboxId = rs.getInt("InboxId");
//                System.out.println(inboxId);
            }
            
            String sql2 = "select * from message where inboxId = int";//this is where i need help
            p = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            rs = p.executeQuery();
         
            // Printing ID, name, email of customers
            // of the SQL command above
            System.out.println("Inbox:");
            
        }
 
        // Catch block to handle exception
        catch (SQLException e) {
 
            // Print exception pop-up on screen
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Once I get the inboxId, I want to run sql2 and pass inboxId as int. How can I do this. Each user will have a different inboxId so thats why to get the user inbox I want to extract and messages in the message table that are meant for inboxId of the user.

I tried the query string sql and it works now I just need to fix String sql2.

Comment: String sql2 = "select * from message where inboxId = "+ inboxId;

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan I did that but im getting error "local variable inboxId may not have been intialized". I initialized it in the while loop. Does that mean the value is only initialized within the scope of the while loop? If so how can I fix this.

Comment: It is trying to tell you that there is a possibility that the while condition can be false, this means that you can't use the variable until you assign a value to it.

Comment: Ok thanks I initialized it to zero then.

Answer (score 0):

`String sql2 = "select * from message where inboxId = " + 1234;`

1234 could be a variable. You could also use `String.format()` to do it as well.

`String sql2 = String.format("select * from message where inboxId = %d", 1234);`

Comment: I did "String sql2 = "select * from message where inboxId = "+ inboxId;" I did that but im getting error "local variable inboxId may not have been intialized". I initialized it in the while loop. Does that mean the value is only initialized within the scope of the while loop? If so how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
  String sql2 = "select * from message where inboxId = ?"; //The ? indicates a variable in the prepared statement.
  p = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
  p.setInt(1, inboxId);
  rs = p.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I did "String sql2 = "select * from message where inboxId = "+ inboxId;" I did that but im getting error "local variable inboxId may not have been intialized". I initialized it in the while loop. Does that mean the value is only initialized within the scope of the while loop? If so how can I fix this.

Comment: Since you only set it inside the while look, the compiles is unable to determine that it will always be initialized and it may not actually be initialized (if the first call to rs.next() returned false).
Solve by initializing it to a reasonable value.  Possibly `int inboxId = -1;`  I assume that -1 will never be a real value in the db.

Comment: Hi how would I be able to do this if there are 2 unknown values for variables. Please take a look. In this statement both senderID and receiverID are unknown. This is the sql statement: "select * from message where senderID = ? AND receiverID = ?". Both senderID and receiverID are pass are arguments for this method. But how can I pass them in the SQL query.

Comment: I tried the following: String sql2 = "select * from message where senderID = ? AND recieverID = ?"; 
            p = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            rs = p.executeQuery();
            p.setInt(1, senderId);
            p.setInt(1, recieverId);